# Havishyana and prohibition on use of oil and soap during sutak

Tags: death, garuda-purana, birth, antyeshti

There are some rules I read on multiple sites that need to be followed during ashouch/sutak. Only *havishyana* (i.e boiled food that can be offered in havan) should be consumed till the 10th day. Cooking in oil and even application of oil or soap should be avoided. I don't remember them being mentioned in the Garud Purana . So are these rules backed by any scriptural reference? Apart from Garud Purana are there other books which tell about the prohibitions during sutak period after death or birth?